# How to select a particular section of JSON Data in R?

Tags: json, r, excel

I am trying to import data from url into R which is in the form of JSON, then export it to an Excel file.

**url**: https://api.typeform.com/v1/form/JlCM2J?key=ecab3f590a2af4ca55468adc95686a043bbf6c9a

This is my R code

```
library(data.table)
library(httr)
library(rjson)

set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))

var1=fread('https://api.typeform.com/v1/form/JlCM2J?key=ecab3f590a2af4ca55468adc95686a043bbf6c9a')

head(var1)
```

**Output:**

> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 161 cols: {"http_status":200,stats":{"responses":{"showing":2,"total":2,"completed":1}},"questions":[{"id":"textfield_38991412,question":"What is your first name?,field_id":38991412},{"id":"statement_38991416,question":"HiÂ {{answer_38991412}},Thank you for taking this questionnaire.Your answers will help us build a great brand for you.Â One that is strong and memorable in your customers' minds. One that defines clearly what you are, what you stand for, and what makes you different.Let's get started!,field_id":38991416},{"id":"group_38991407...

**Need:**
I only need the `responses` section of this data to be exported as an Excel file.
Entire data can be viewed by pasting the above url in the `jsonviewer.stack.hu` site

Comment: `data.table::fread` is for reading tables. The structure you provided is not a table; it is far more structured than that. (I also suggest `jsonlite` in lieu of `rjson`, which hasn't been updated in over 2 years.) Try `x <- readLines(url) ; str(jsonlite::fromJSON(x))` to see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you so much. After changing the code, This is part of the output.. How do I extract the answers data frame alone?

$ answers  :'data.frame': 2 obs. of  26 variables:
  .. ..$ textfield_38991412                : chr [1:2] NA "A"
  .. ..$ dropdown_38991418                 : chr [1:2] NA "Accounting"
  .. ..$ textarea_38991420                 : chr [1:2] NA "A"
.
.

Comment: BTW: when adding significant content and/or actual code/output, it's often much better to edit your question (often with *"Update: ..."*) than to put the output in a comment, much harder to read that way. You should "accept" @hrbrmstr's answer, it's what you need (and is customary).

Answer (score 2):

The following is the more (IMO) idiomatic way to interface with REST APIs in modern R:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

res <- GET("https://api.typeform.com/v1/form/JlCM2J",
           query=list(key="ecab3f590a2af4ca55468adc95686a043bbf6c9a"))

content(res, as="text") %>%
  fromJSON(flatten=FALSE) -> out

glimpse(out$responses$answers)
## Observations: 2
## Variables: 26
## $ textfield_38991412                 <chr> NA, "A"
## $ dropdown_38991418                  <chr> NA, "Accounting"
## $ textarea_38991420                  <chr> NA, "A"
## $ textfield_38991413                 <chr> NA, "A"
## $ textarea_38991421                  <chr> NA, "A"
## $ listimage_38991426_choice          <chr> NA, "Company"
## $ textfield_38991414                 <chr> NA, "A"
## $ website_38991435                   <chr> NA, "http://A.com"
## $ textarea_38991422                  <chr> NA, "A"
## $ listimage_38991427_choice          <chr> NA, "Sincere"
## $ listimage_38991428_choice          <chr> NA, "Male"
## $ list_38991436_choice               <chr> NA, "17 or younger"
## $ list_38991437_choice               <chr> NA, "Upper class"
## $ listimage_38991429_choice_49501105 <chr> NA, "Store"
## $ listimage_38991430_choice          <chr> NA, "Product"
## $ textarea_38991423                  <chr> NA, "A"
## $ listimage_38991431_choice          <chr> NA, "Techy"
## $ listimage_38991432_choice_49501124 <chr> NA, "Fuchsia Rose"
## $ listimage_38991433_choice          <chr> NA, "Classic"
## $ list_38991438_choice               <chr> NA, "$3,000 or less"
## $ listimage_38991434_choice_49501140 <chr> NA, "Brand Design"
## $ textarea_38991424                  <chr> NA, "A"
## $ textfield_38991415                 <chr> NA, "A"
## $ dropdown_38991419                  <chr> NA, "Afghanistan"
## $ email_38991439                     <chr> NA, "A@a.com"
## $ textarea_38991425                  <chr> NA, "A"
```

- Using `httr::GET()` directly will enable easier management of extra parameters.
- Using `httr::content()` to take the response and retrieve the raw text enables finer-grained processing (if needed)
- Using `jsonlite::fromJSON()` directly provides far more granular control over individual JSON processing options.

However, there's an R package `rtypeform` which really simplifies everything (fun fact: it follows the idiom above under the covers):

```
library(rtypeform)
library(dplyr)

res <- get_results("JlCM2J")

glimpse(res$responses$answers)
## Observations: 2
## Variables: 26
## $ textfield_38991412                 <chr> NA, "A"
## $ dropdown_38991418                  <chr> NA, "Accounting"
## $ textarea_38991420                  <chr> NA, "A"
## $ textfield_38991413                 <chr> NA, "A"
## $ textarea_38991421                  <chr> NA, "A"
## $ listimage_38991426_choice          <chr> NA, "Company"
## $ textfield_38991414                 <chr> NA, "A"
## $ website_38991435                   <chr> NA, "http://A.com"
## $ textarea_38991422                  <chr> NA, "A"
## $ listimage_38991427_choice          <chr> NA, "Sincere"
## $ listimage_38991428_choice          <chr> NA, "Male"
## $ list_38991436_choice               <chr> NA, "17 or younger"
## $ list_38991437_choice               <chr> NA, "Upper class"
## $ listimage_38991429_choice_49501105 <chr> NA, "Store"
## $ listimage_38991430_choice          <chr> NA, "Product"
## $ textarea_38991423                  <chr> NA, "A"
## $ listimage_38991431_choice          <chr> NA, "Techy"
## $ listimage_38991432_choice_49501124 <chr> NA, "Fuchsia Rose"
## $ listimage_38991433_choice          <chr> NA, "Classic"
## $ list_38991438_choice               <chr> NA, "$3,000 or less"
## $ listimage_38991434_choice_49501140 <chr> NA, "Brand Design"
## $ textarea_38991424                  <chr> NA, "A"
## $ textfield_38991415                 <chr> NA, "A"
## $ dropdown_38991419                  <chr> NA, "Afghanistan"
## $ email_38991439                     <chr> NA, "A@a.com"
## $ textarea_38991425                  <chr> NA, "A"
```

Either way, this must be your first time using R (or almost your first time) if you aren't used to using `$` to access fields in lists. You should really spend some time learning R before trying to work with API data. Incorrect results and self-frustration are the only things you're going to get in return for cut-paste-and-praying your way through coding. You still need to get this into a CSV file (`write.csv()` for that).

Penultimately, if you're just going to end up using Excel, why are you programmatically retrieving the form responses? If you're not going to use R for the rest of the work, this seems like a needless step unless you're trying to script the download of the data vs make someone login to the site to fetch it.

Finally, **invalidate and re-generate your API key immediately** since you posted it in an open forum. I now know you have 2 forms: "Branding Questionnaire" and "Test Form" and will be able to monitor what you do in Typeform and retrieve any of your form data at-will. The `rtypeform` package will let you store your API key in the `typeform_api` environment variable (you can use the `~/.Renviron` to hold this data) so you never have to expose it to the world again in your scripts.

Comment: +1 for "penultimately", "invalidate your API key", and `rtypeform`. Interesting use of `->`, perhaps non-standard though some suggest it adds readability (not yet for me :-).

Comment: Heads up, the raw JSON only has one element per field in `res$responses$answers` but `jsonlite` is adding a row of `NA`. (I see it on mine, too.) If you cut "just" `...$answers` out of the JSON and decode it, you'll get a 1-row data.frame, but because the top `$responses` pops as a data.frame and 3 of its "columns" are loosely "length 2", it extends `...$hidden` and `...$answers`. I don't think this is a "bug" per se, more an artifact of the data structure.

Comment: Aye. I saw the `NA` row and poked a bit. It's a pretty clunky data structure all around. They shld have made a way to just d/l the CSV answers via API vs jump through JSON hoops.

Comment: Ya, the user of `fromJSON(res, simplifyVector=FALSE)` might help, ala `as.data.frame(fromJSON(res, simplifyVector = FALSE)$responses[[2]]$answers)`.