# scraping table with rvest (XHR file)

Tags: r

i have a question, How can I get the link [http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Advanced&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2016-17&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=](http://i%20have%20a%20question,%20How%20can%20I%20get%20the%20link%20http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Advanced&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2016-17&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=) in the instruccion get() in the post [Scraping table of NBA stats with rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603100/scraping-table-of-nba-stats-with-rvest/46800413#46800413)

Please, help me, I tried to search but I did not find the way to get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing I saw prevented scraping, but I saw this (http://www.bmv.com.mx/en/information-products/web-services) which may indicate they expect to be paid for other data dumps (I don't know enough about this to know if this data falls into that cagetory).

Use the browser Developer Tools to look for the calls that are made to fetch the dynamic data. In the "XHR" sub-tab under the Network tab you'll see http://www.bmv.com.mx/en/Grupo_BMV/BmvJsonGeneric?idSitioPagina=4&random=4267 which is the javascript data that makes the paginated table.

They put in a sneaky safeguard with a forever-repeating `for`-loop but we can surgically remove it, evaluate it in a javascript V8 context and extract the data that makes the page:

```
library(httr)
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
library(V8)
```

Setup our javascript context:

```
ctx <- v8()
```

Get the target URL. These seemed to be the minimum required headers.

```
GET(
  url = "http://www.bmv.com.mx/en/Grupo_BMV/BmvJsonGeneric?idSitioPagina=4&random=4267", 
  add_headers(
    `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36", 
    Accept = "text/plain, */*; q=0.01", 
    Referer = "http://www.bmv.com.mx/en/markets/equity", 
    `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest"
  ),
  encode = "form"
) -> res
```

Now we do some surgery to get rid of the infinite `for`-loop and evaluate the javascript:

```
content(res, as="text") %>% 
  stri_replace_first_fixed("for(;;);(", "") %>% 
  stri_replace_last_regex("\\)\n<.*$", "") %>% 
  sprintf("var x = %s", .) %>%
  ctx$eval()
```

We now retrieve the data:

```
x <- ctx$get("x")
```

And do some basic munging to get it into a form we can use:

```
select(x$response$resultado$A, -datosEstadistica) %>% 
  bind_cols(x$response$resultado$A$datosEstadistica) %>% 
  tbl_df() %>% 
  glimpse()
## Observations: 129
## Variables: 97
## $ idEmision                    <int> 1959, 6096, 6982, 336310, 339083, 30, 7684, 1729, 1861, 1862, 361720, 6507, 671, 1827, 4...
## $ idFormapago                  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ idMoneda                     <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ idEstatusemi                 <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ idTpmercado                  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ idSubtpvalor                 <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ idTpvalor                    <chr> "1", "1", "1", "1E", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1E", "1B", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", ...
## $ idPartxemp                   <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ cveSerie                     <chr> "*", "B", "*", "*", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "L", "*", "10", "*", "B", "B", "CPO", "CPO"...
## $ fechaEmision                 <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ fechaCreacion                <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ creadoPor                    <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ monto                        <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ sistema                      <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ impCirculacion               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ operaBmv                     <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ valEjercidos                 <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ operaCierre                  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ autorizadoVc                 <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ idTpedoperacion              <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ cveEmision                   <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ idBursatilidad               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ cveCorta                     <chr> "AC", "ACTINVR", "AEROMEX", "AG", "AGUA", "ALFA", "ALPEK", "ALSEA", "AMX", "AMX", "ANB",...
## $ erogacionNeta                <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ valNominal                   <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ fechaPropagint               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ fechaUltaut                  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ fechaVencto                  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ cuponVigente                 <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ fechaModificacion            <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ modificadoPor                <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ fechaUltpagint               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ tasaNeta                     <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ tasaBruta                    <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ cveCupon                     <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ valInscritos                 <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ valCirculacion               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ precioEjercido               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ prima                        <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ operaSentra                  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ isin                         <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ factorVincula                <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ tipoWarrant                  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ precioValoresSubyacentes     <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ calculaInteres               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ tipoLiquidacion              <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ fechaAjuste                  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ minimoEjercer                <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ valorMoneda                  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ porcentajeRendimientoLimitad <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ importeRendimientoLimitado   <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ cobertura                    <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ fechaCnbv                    <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ folioCnbv                    <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ inscritaRnv                  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ porcentajePrimaRetornable    <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ importePrimaRetornable       <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ restricciones                <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ desfaseDiasPeriodoCupon      <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ emisora                      <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ estatus                      <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ descripcion                  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ fideicomitente               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ representante                <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ idEmisora                    <int> 6081, 6842, 7567, 31398, 31600, 5052, 5057, 5059, 6024, 6024, 32295, 7421, 5072, 6001, 5...
## $ hora                         <chr> "03:10", "03:10", "03:10", "03:10", "03:10", "03:10", "03:10", "03:10", "03:10", "03:10"...
## $ ultimo                       <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ horaUltimoValor              <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ horaValorMaximo              <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ horaValorMinimo              <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ anterior                     <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ maximo                       <chr> "127.48", "13", "32.82", "131.11", "28.8", "20.3", "19.87", "60.45", "17.04", "17.36", "...
## $ minimo                       <chr> "124.81", "12.85", "30.74", "131.11", "26.24", "18.6", "18", "59.15", "17.01", "17.03", ...
## $ importeAcomulado             <dbl> 1.419413e+08, 7.404591e+05, 5.948047e+06, 7.890214e+04, 4.219719e+06, 5.939556e+08, 1.13...
## $ valorAcomulado               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ noOperaciones                <int> 5526, 18, 1474, 3, 994, 13386, 4922, 6094, 12, 32374, 2, 6, 1413, 10454, 494, 2782, 1821...
## $ variacionPuntos              <dbl> 0.49, -0.01, 0.73, -6.90, 0.71, 0.63, 1.17, -0.73, 0.04, 0.16, 8.93, 0.48, 0.14, 8.99, -...
## $ variacionPorcentual          <dbl> 0.39, -0.08, 2.30, -5.00, 2.56, 3.25, 6.38, -1.21, 0.24, 0.94, 0.38, 1.78, 2.24, 2.62, -...
## $ fecha                        <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ volumenVenta                 <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ volumenCompra                <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ posturaVenta                 <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ posturaCompra                <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ precioUltimoHecho            <dbl> 125.83, 12.85, 32.25, 131.11, 28.50, 20.00, 19.75, 59.79, 17.04, 17.20, 2387.38, 27.46, ...
## $ ppp                          <dbl> 126.16, 12.85, 32.52, 131.11, 28.48, 20.01, 19.50, 59.79, 0.00, 17.23, 0.00, 27.46, 6.39...
## $ precioAnterior               <dbl> 125.67, 12.86, 31.79, 138.01, 27.77, 19.38, 18.33, 60.52, 17.00, 17.07, 2378.45, 26.98, ...
## $ volumenOperado               <int> 1130931, 57586, 187357, 601, 150260, 30022236, 5977695, 3515871, 5542, 84667705, 200, 86...
## $ maxAnioAnterio               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ minAnioAnterior              <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ primerTrimestre              <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ precioUtilidad               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ precioValorLibro             <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ utilidadAccion               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ valorLibroAccion             <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ accionesCirculacion          <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
## $ anioEjercicio                <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
## $ idTpOperacion                <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...
```

It's possible to derive this target URL from the other components loaded by the page but that wasn't your question, so hopefully this helps.