# Web scraping tables in R -- null table list returned despite 2 tables present

Tags: r, json, web-scraping

I'm trying scrape the NBA lineup data from https://www.nba.com/stats/lineups/advanced

the goal is to download the whole table, all 2000 rows, however currently I can't seem to locate the data within the html nodes. I have tried a few different methods so far:

The first is with rvest and dyplyr;

**First method**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

linups_link <- "https://www.nba.com/stats/lineups/advanced"
lineups_page <- read_html(linups_link)

lineups_table <- lineups_page %>% html_nodes("table") %>%
     html_table() %>% .[[1]]
```

(I've also tried nba-stat-table; table.table; .stats-container-next.nba-stat-table.table as other nodes but none worked either -- same error)

this consistently throws the following:
`Error in .[[1]] : subscript out of bounds` so I decided to just run the `lineups_table <- lineups_page %>% html_nodes("table")`  section and what I get is an empty list. This confuses me, because there is clearly a table and so I tried another method:

**Second method**

After searching a little I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603100/scraping-table-of-nba-stats-with-rvest) and [this thread -- both about querying JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436723/how-to-select-a-particular-section-of-json-data-in-r/41441845#41441845). This is new territory for me, but I followed the response by Dave2e and tried to use httr and jsonlite:

```
nba_lineups<- GET('https://www.nba.com/stats/lineups/advanced')

nba_lineups_out <- content(nba_lineups, as="text") %>% fromJSON(flatten=F)
```

But this gave an error too:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns:ng=
                     (right here) ------^
```

and nba_lineups seems to be a list of lists containing information about the html, but not the data itself. Having not used JSON before, this is where I start to lose the forest for the trees

**Third method**

Next I tried to manually search for the tables in the web-dev console by using
`var i = 1; [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('table'), function(x) { console.log(i++, x); });`

and that returned 2 results, the first of which highlighted the table that I'm interested in (and confirms that the html_nodes("table") should be a non-empty string, at least according to what I understand). The table in question, indexed 1, has null strings for the accesKey and accessKeyLabel attributes, but is a "table" class.

Since I couldn't figure it out in R with what I did before, I tried using google sheets to import the html and that returned a null result as well.

**Fourth method**

I'll be brief, because these latter 2 aren't germane to R scraping, but I tried to used selectorgadget in crhome to grab the xml paths for the table and that resulted in the same null table at the end of the importxml read with the URL and xml path passed as arguments

I'm hoping to use these lineups for some analyses, and I can't find another site that has this data set available. Does anyone know how to scrape this data set (preferably in R?)

Comment: How frequently do you need to scrape/update the data?  It's possible to get the JSON data using the network panel within the dev tools, however, it looks like they've restricted network traffic to their own domain, so it's likely not possible to automate.   Also, it's likely the table is appearing empty when scraping because the data actually loads in to the table via javascript well after the page is initially loaded.

Comment: I don't really need to scrape/update it at all. Once I have it downloaded into a manageable format I'll be happy. This won't be part of an ongoing or interactive project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Chrome's developer tools (could be done with another browser as well), open the **Network panel** (seen at the top of the attached screenshot).  It'll be easiest to **filter the results** using the input box on the left, towards the top (I used the string `dashlineups`), then **refresh the page**.  Once their page makes the request, you'll see it populate here.  Click on the one that has response data, then **copy the response data**.  This can be pasted into a text editor and saved as a json file.  From there you should be able to use a package like `jsonlite` to read the newly created file.

[image]

Comment: This looks like it worked perfectly, thank you

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you know to filter to the "dashLineups" string?

Comment: Honestly, I just scanned the list for something that looked promising.  There was no guarantee the data would be loaded in a way that would work, but I was hopeful :). You can add a "URL" column to that Network view, which also helps tease out potential requests (helps to ignore things like advertising, google analytics, and the like)